# Maintaining login credentials across pages in HTMLunit WebClient

Tags: java, webclient, htmlunit

My question is very similar to the one at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388546/passing-basic-auth-credentials-with-every-request-with-htmlunit-webclient), except that I don't have access to the remote server, nor know how it does its authentication.

I'm trying to maintain logged in status across webpages that I can request using webclient.getPage(). The website I'm accessing uses a standard login form with username, password pair. What I've done before is to create a little function to do that for me:

```
public static HtmlPage logIn(HtmlPage page) {
    HtmlPage nextpage = null;
    final HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("login_form");
    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue("Login");
    final HtmlTextInput username = form.getInputByName("username");
    final HtmlPasswordInput password = form.getInputByName("password");
    username.setValueAttribute("user_foo");
    password.setValueAttribute("pwd_bar");      

    // hit submit button and return the requested page
    try {
        nextpage = button.click();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return nextpage;
}
```

The problem with this is that I have to manually search the page returned by this function in order to find the link to the page I want. More troubling is that this only works for the page right after login, but for not other pages.

Instead, I would like to hold the login information within the browser simulator, "webclient", so that I can seamlessly access any protected page within the site. In addition to attempting the solution in the previous question (linked above), I have attempted the following solution without success:

```
private static void setCredentials(WebClient webClient) {
    String username = "user_foo";
    String password = "pwd_bar";
    DefaultCredentialsProvider creds = (DefaultCredentialsProvider) webClient.getCredentialsProvider();//new DefaultCredentialsProvider();
    try {
        creds.addCredentials(username, password);
    webClient.setCredentialsProvider(creds);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("!!! Problem login in");
        e.printStackTrace();            
}
```

Edited: here is the main function showing how I use webClient:

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
    // Create and initialize WebClient object
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(/*BrowserVersion.CHROME_16*/);
    webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    webClient.setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    setCredentials(webClient);

    HtmlPage subj_page = null;
    //visit login page and get it
    String url = "http://www.website.com/index.php";
    HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(url);
    HtmlAnchor anchor = null;
    page = logIn(page);

    // search for content
    page = searchPage(page, "recent articles");     

    // click on the paper link      
    anchor = (HtmlAnchor) page.getAnchorByText("recent articles");
    page = (HtmlPage) anchor.click();

    // loop through found articles
    //{{{page
    int curr_pg = 1;
    int last_pg = 5;        
    page = webClient.getPage(<starting URL of the first article>); // such URLs look like: "www.website.com/view_articles.php?publication_id=17&page=1"
    do {
        // find sections on this page; 
        List <HtmlDivision> sections = new ArrayList<HtmlDivision>();
        List <HtmlDivision> artdivs = new ArrayList<HtmlDivision>();
        List <HtmlDivision> tagdivs = new ArrayList<HtmlDivision>();
        sections = (List<HtmlDivision>) page.getByXPath("//div[@class='article_section']");
        artdivs = (List<HtmlDivision>) page.getByXPath("//div[@class='article_head']");
        tagdivs = (List<HtmlDivision>) page.getByXPath("//div[@class='article_tag']");          

        int num_ques = sections.size();
        HtmlDivision section, artdiv, tagdiv;

        // for every section, get its sub-articles
        for (int i = 0; i < num_ques; i++) {
            section = sections.get(i);
            artdiv = artdivs.get(i);
            tagdiv = tagdivs.get(i);

            // find the sub-article details and print to xml file
            String xml = getXMLArticle(artdiv, section.asText(), tagdiv);
            System.out.println(xml);
            System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        }
        //remove IllegalMonitorStateException *
        synchronized (webClient) { 
            webClient.wait(2000); // wait for 2 seconds             
        }

        String href = "?publication_id=17&page=" + curr_pg;
        anchor = page.getAnchorByHref(href);            
        page = anchor.click();
        System.out.println("anchor val: " + anchor.getHrefAttribute());
        curr_pg++;
    } while (curr_pg < last_pg);
    //}}}page

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

Other info: I do not have info about the remote site server's authentication mechanism since I have no access to it, but your help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: How do you access the other pages, after login, and what happens when you do it? Show us the code.

Comment: @JBNizet, just posted the main code above. the implementation of getXMLArticle() is not important, since it doesn't need the webClient.  Let me know if you need any other info :)